# What do you mean by windows media service (Live and on demand)

Tags: video-streaming, windows

I have one enquiry from my end customer regarding windows media streaming services (Live and on Demand)

One Publishing point for live audio stream (push to server method) for windows Media 9 streaming service; shall be able to stream to a maximum of 1600 users at 48 kbps (live) or equivalent (in combination with content of higher  bit rate from  on demand service); RSTP; HTTP 1.0/1.1; AT least 2 GB of hard drive space for on demand  content :

they have told a QTY of 5

What does this  mean and is this some kind of software or service?

Comment: 48KBps*1600 = 75MBps, which reqires sustained throughput of 600Mbps. That's very hefty, expensive bandwidth - it's going to be expensive.

Answer (score 2):

What they're asking for is Windows Media Services, an add-on for Windows Server that allows it to handle streaming media. WMS is available for both Server 2003 and 2008/2008R2. Both allow streaming live events, streaming pre-recorded files, and download-and-play.

Live streaming is handled by a recording device somewhere in the field pushing to the server, which then relays it to subscribing clients.

It's a standard Microsoft service.

Comment: so where should i contact to get more details for this one, I am supposed send a quote to them.

Comment: google or microsoft. Windows Media Services is not THAT hard to find as a search term.